# Flex : Can we add images in spark text area (StyleableTextField) through htmlText property for Tablet App using Flex 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I need to know can we add image in TextArea through StyleableTextField htmlText because my app for device Tablet. (Not possible to use TextLayoutFramework) or Anyother possible to add image into any text component?

Thanks

Comment: @Raja_Jaganathan adding the image is not possible in text area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In StyleableTextField not possible in this case. But you we can use RichEditableText instead.
RichEditableText  support TLF so we can add image but not optimized for mobile still we can RichEditableText  component work smoothly in iPad.